# Predicting outcome with ordinally, continuously or linearly related predictor variables

Tags: regression, ordinal-data, count-data, continuous-data, independence

I am attempting to predict the number of chicks that will hatch from a group of eggs stored in a box. My predictor variable is the count of the eggs based on their size, such as "THE NUMBER OF THE EGGS WHICH HAS SIZE OF 11mm", "THE NUMBER OF THE EGGS WHICH HAS SIZE OF 12mm", and so on ...

I have data on the number of eggs of each size that were placed in the box, as well as the number of chicks that hatched from the same box.

For instance, if I conduct a regression model that disregards the continuous relationship among predictors, the model would appear as follows: (where "TNOTEWHSO" stands for "THE NUMBER OF THE EGG WHICH HAS SIZE OF")

$$ Y = \beta1* "TNOTEWHSO 11mm" + \beta2*"TNOTEWHSO 12mm" + \beta 3*"TNOTEWHSO 13mm" + ..... + \beta20*"TNOTEWHSO 30mm"$$

Suppose there is a continuous, linear, ordinal, or quadratic relationship between different predictor variables' effects on the count of chicks, based on the order of their numbers.
(This means Beta coefficient of "TNOTEWHSO 12mm" must be possibly between "TNOTEWHSO 11mm" and "TNOTEWHSO 13mm"

What is the appropriate statistical analysis to account for the continuous structure of the predictor variables?

Comment: You could look into splines (or if the number of distinct levels is low, maybe a quadratic regression)

Comment: The number of distinct levels is 20. As you see above, there are 20 beta coefficients. However the continuous relation is between beta estimates. Not between the count variables and y. The values of Beta estimates should continuously follow each other. For a different perspective of this problem, you can use the link below;

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/606693/how-should-i-analyze-longitudinal-data-with-missing-observations-for-individuals

Comment: Then maybe have a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/382117/is-this-a-valid-work-around-for-collinearity