# How should I analyze longitudinal data with missing observations for individuals? Expectation Maximization or panel data analysis or regression? How?

Tags: mixed-model, panel-data, missing-data, biostatistics, expectation-maximization

I possess a dataset containing 1,000 chickens. For each chicken, we have egg count data for various sizes (11 to 22mm) and the overall number of chicks that hatched from these eggs for each chiken.

What is the appropriate statistical analysis to determine the probability of producing a chick for each egg size?

Data of first 4 chicken is presented as follows:

[image]

or in another format;

[image]

Comment: So you do not have total chick count for each egg (0/1), only total for each chicken? If so, information about *probability of producing a chick for each egg size* must come from varying egg size distribution within chickens

Comment: Is it correct to say that the "missing data" in this situation is just that you don't know the sizes of the specific eggs that led to live chicks? Do you nevertheless have data on the sizes of all of the eggs originally laid and the actual numbers of live chicks per chicken?

Answer (score 0):

This is reasonably straightforward, if you can assume that the probability of a chick hatching at any given egg size is independent of the chicken that laid the egg, the sizes of other eggs laid by the chicken, etc. In that case, you have a single probability $p_j$ for the probability of a live chick hatch from an egg in size group $j$.

For egg-laying chicken $i$, the estimated number of live-hatched chicks $C_i$ would then be the sum of the products of those probabilities times its number of eggs $N_{ij}$ in each size group $j$:

$$C_i = \sum_{j=11}^{j=22} p_j N_{ij}.$$

That suggests a simple linear multiple regression of total chick counts as the outcome versus its number of eggs in each size group (12 predictors). Your first data display is already set up for that. The coefficient for each size group $j$ would be the estimated probability of a live hatch at that size.

This might ideally be handled in a way that respected the count-based outcome values, perhaps a Poisson regression but with an identity link instead of the default log link. With this large a dataset and about an 80:1 ratio of observations to estimated coefficients, however, a simple linear regression might be good enough.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! A poisson regression with an identity link makes sense since the $Ci$ would have possibly poisson distribution and the mean parameter of this distribution would be the sum of the products of those probabilities times its # of eggs. However the main problem is this; consecutive $p_j$ should have continuous relation. For example the probability of having chicken should first monotonously increase, reach the max then decrease, since there can be also error in measuring the size of the eggs, the consecutive eggs should have close probabilities of having chick.

Comment: @insan if your hypotheses of a monotonic increase and decrease with size and similar $p_j$ estimates for consecutive sizes are correct, then you should be able to see those patterns in the 12 $p_j$ estimates. If you can't, then those hypotheses or other hypotheses (the same survival/egg-size association for all chickens, or independence among eggs laid by the same chicken) don't hold. A Bayesian approach might work, where you could take into account errors in egg size and assume a smooth continuous association between true egg size and survival, but that's beyond my expertise.